# Flash File Upload Fails with 401 for IE11

Tags: flash, file-upload, internet-explorer-11, http-status-code-401

When I use chrome to upload the file, the first request results in a 401, but then subsequently, reauthorizes the user and succeeds. However, in IE11 no further requests are made after the initial 401.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

IE11:

- FileLinkUpload.aspx `401`

  `POST /Services/FileLinkUpload.aspx HTTP/1.1
  Accept: text/*
  Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------Ef1KM7ae0ei4gL6cH2KM7cH2Ef1gL6
  User-Agent: Shockwave Flash
  Host: mywebsite.com
  Content-Length: 1159570
  Pragma: no-cache
  Cookie: s_cc=true; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; ASP.NET_SessionId=rj0yo5aacceizew0c31htkd0
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  ...`

Chrome:

- FileLinkUpload.aspx `401`

  `POST /Services/FileLinkUpload.aspx HTTP/1.1
  Host: mywebsite.com
  Content-Length: 99837
  Origin: http://mywebsite.com
  X-Requested-With: ShockwaveFlash/16.0.0.305
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
  Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------cH2cH2ae0Ef1ae0ei4ei4Ij5Ef1ei4
  Accept: */*
  Referer: http://mywebsite.com/
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
  Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6
  Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=4krdvepcftd4ojfkg0ydsfz1
  Pragma: no-cache
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  ...`
- FileLinkUpload.aspx `401`

  `POST /Services/FileLinkUpload.aspx HTTP/1.1
  Host: mywebsite.com
  Content-Length: 99837
  Origin: http://mywebsite.com
  X-Requested-With: ShockwaveFlash/16.0.0.305
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
  Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------cH2cH2ae0Ef1ae0ei4ei4Ij5Ef1ei4
  Accept: */*
  Referer: http://mywebsite.com/
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
  Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6
  Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=4krdvepcftd4ojfkg0ydsfz1
  Pragma: no-cache
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Authorization: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAl7II4gYABgA3AAAADwAPACgAAAAGAbEdAAAAD0FCTFNDQVNNQURMVTAwN1FBLUVOVA==
  ...`
- FileLinkUpload.aspx `200`

  `POST /Services/FileLinkUpload.aspx HTTP/1.1
  Host: mywebsite.com
  Content-Length: 99837
  Origin: http://mywebsite.com
  X-Requested-With: ShockwaveFlash/16.0.0.305
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
  Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------cH2cH2ae0Ef1ae0ei4ei4Ij5Ef1ei4
  Accept: */*
  Referer: http://mywebsite.com/
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
  Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6
  Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=4krdvepcftd4ojfkg0ydsfz1
  Pragma: no-cache
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Authorization: Negotiate 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
  ...`

Answer (score 1):

In IE request headers you have the following `Accept: text/*`
, however in chrome you have `Accept: */*` . Also you have `X-Requested-With: ShockwaveFlash/16.0.0.305` in chrome request and not in IE, I think you need to verify that all your headers are correct for IE request.

Comment: It's done through flash player in both cases, but it looks like the hand off to the browser is done differently